# Toggle a single class in a group

Tags: jquery, toggle, toggleclass

I want to toggle plus / minus icons on click on an accordian menu, the code I have at the moment changes all of the icons, how do I only switch the one which is clicked? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<a href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse"><div class="panel-heading prod-panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">Compare Prices <b class="prod-ico glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></b></h4>
</div></a>
```

jQuery:

```
// toggle product tab icons
$(".prod-panel-heading").live("click", function() {

   $(".prod-ico").toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign");  

});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is now deprecated/removed and [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (in jQuery 1.7+) should be used instead. Prior to jQuery 1.7 the jQuery team (or the authors of their API pages, in the documentation for `live()`) recommend [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) be used instead, for better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".prod-panel-heading").on("click", function() {

   $(".prod-ico", this).toggleClass("glyphicon-minus-sign").toggleClass("glyphicon-plus-sign");  

});
```

Adding `this` after the class selector will point to all the classes belonging to the class you add a function to. Without it, you point to all the classes of the entire page.